How to make GTK interface work with asyncio?
I'm trying to write a Python program with a GTK interface that gets output from functions using async/await that take a few seconds to execute, what I'm asking for is the best solution for running this while not freezing the GUI..
I was using threads before and sort of got it working, but both the GUI and the backend need to communicate both ways and sometimes at a high rate (every time the user types a new character into a search box, for instance)
and then I found out the 'backend' I'm using also supports async/await so I thought if I could figure out how to get GTK events to play nicely with asyncio, that would probably be the best option..
I've written an example of what I'm trying to do
import asyncio
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


async def simulate_get_results():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    return ['Imagine these are results from an API']


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.search_button = Gtk.Button(label='Press me')

        async def button_pressed(button: Gtk.Button):
            results = await simulate_get_results()
            button.set_label(results[0])

        def non_async_button_callback_wrapper(button: Gtk.Button):
            asyncio.run(button_pressed(button))

        self.search_button.connect('clicked', non_async_button_callback_wrapper)
        self.add(self.search_button)


win = Window()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()

if you can get this to work in a way that it doesn't freeze the GUI after clicking the button, but still displays the results 5 seconds later, you'll most likely have solved my problem

One option to implement this is to merge event loops as shown in the other answer. The downside of that approach is that it tends to lead to CPU churn, as each event loop busy-loops to avoid blocking the other. An alternative approach is to run both event loops normally, each in its own thread. The GTK event loop insists to run in the main thread, so we'd spawn the asyncio event loop in a background thread, like this:
_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
def run_loop():
    # run asyncio loop and wait forever
    threading.Thread(target=_loop.run_forever, daemon=True).start()
run_loop()

With that in place, we can write a function that submits a coroutine to the running event loop, using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe. Furthermore, we set up a callback that notifies us when the coroutine is done, and invokes some code in the GTK thread, using GLib.idle_add to do so:
def submit(coro, when_done):
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, _loop)
    def call_when_done():
        when_done(fut.result())
    fut.add_done_callback(lambda _: GLib.idle_add(call_when_done))

With the submit function in place, you can run any async code from GTK without blocking the GUI, and be notified when it's done by executing a callback invoked in the GTK thread, which can update the GUI accordingly. While the callback-when-done approach is not quite as convenient as the code in the question (where the async function runs asyncio and gtk code interchangeably), it is still practical. It would be used like this:
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.search_button = Gtk.Button(label='Press me')

        def non_async_button_callback_wrapper(button: Gtk.Button):
            submit(simulate_get_results(), lambda results: button.set_label(results[0]))

        self.search_button.connect('clicked', non_async_button_callback_wrapper)
        self.add(self.search_button)

The rest of the code is unchanged. (Full code.)

Yes, I for sure noticed that the CPU was chugging with that first solution, however this one seems to have some problems shutting down, I will attempt to figure that out myself, I suppose. Thanks!

@GrassLunatic The simplest way is to add daemon=True argument to the Thread() constructor.

@GrassLunatic A more graceful asyncio shutdown can be achieved by replacing target=_loop.run_forever with target=lambda: _loop.run_until_complete(_done.wait()) where _done is an asyncio.Event. After quitting the GTK main loop you can tell asyncio to exit using _loop.call_soon_threadsafe(_done.set). Complete code

If one of these approaches work for you, I'll amend the answer to include it. The nice thing about this solution, IMHO, is that it contains less magic than the alternative. But of course, the lunch is never entirely free...

Ok thanks, in fact I found your code easier to understand than the first answer, Also I apologize for wasting everyone's time with the 5 second delay, I don't know what I was thinking, haha.

I find the creation of an event loop in a new thread and then handing it coroutines to be easier to understand as well as fixing the CPU issue, this is the best answer so far.

There is nothing "magic" on the asyncio assuming the role main loop of GTK - it is the way asynchronous programing is designed and expected to work: single-threaded concurrency, and it is a proven model to make better use of CPU resources. If GTK is good running in a separate thread (not all UI frameworks are), and there is active CPU computing needed on the GTK side (like keep some animating running), separating the threads might be a better option. Otherwise, it is also the change that requires less changes in code - but not the way to think about  "async".

Ah, on the very first paragraph in your answer there is the statement that GTK is picky about threads and demands the main thread for itself. Incorporating GTK updates in the async code in the main thread has even more  "pros" them. Of course, no means are "absolute".

@jsbueno Yeah, the GTK threading requirement is addressed by just keeping the UI loop in the main thread. The reason I consider your answer more "magical" (and perhaps a bit of a hack) is that it doesn't run either the GTK main loop nor the asyncio one in the normal way, but rolls its own hybrid by running iterations in a busy loop. It does use public APIs to do that, but such code attracts bugs, and it further wastes CPU cycles and prevents the machine from going to sleep. It's not something I'd recommend to be used in production.

The thing is both asynchronous programing and GTK programing "require" an event-loop: i.e., they get control of the whole application, and as I/O or scheduled events appear, they are dispatched to the respective components (which may in turn trigger other events).
The thing to do then is to unify those, so that a single event loop can dispatch events to both "realms" of the app. Asyncio is built from the ground-up for this - and gtk3 also supports it with a call that runs a single interation of its event loop, without blocking. So, if we keep calling this function -  namely Gtk.main_interation_do - from a task running in the asyncio Loop, all the GTK side of the application can run smoothly, while all tasks, events and whatnot on the asyncio side can also be executed.
Besides that, it is just a matter of wrapping things so all tasks are proper finallized. (I could not find out if a finalizator out of "gtk_main_quit" should be called for Gtk if it is not running its event loop)
Here is your example code modified to work as described above:
import asyncio
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

event_tasks = set()

counter = 0
async def simulate_get_results():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return [f'Imagine these are results from an API - {counter}']


class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.search_button = Gtk.Button(label='Press me')

        async def button_pressed(button: Gtk.Button):
            # Await can be used normally
            results = await simulate_get_results()
            self.search_button.set_label(results[0])

        def sync_button_callback_wrapper(button: Gtk.Button):
            # Create the asynchronus task and let it run when the asyncio loop gets a chance:
            event_tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(button_pressed(button)))

        self.search_button.connect('clicked', sync_button_callback_wrapper)
        self.add(self.search_button)


async def async_gtk_main():
    while not finalize_app:
        # do one iteration of the GTK mainloop:
        Gtk.main_iteration_do(False)
        # yield control to asyncio mainloop so other tasks can run - 
        # But we also want to wait on event-tasks and mark then as awaited:
        if event_tasks:
            done, _ = await asyncio.wait(event_tasks, timeout=0)
            event_tasks.difference_update(done)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

def async_terminate(_):
    global finalize_app
    for task in event_tasks:
        task.cancel()
    finalize_app = True

finalize_app = False
win = Window()
# win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
win.connect('destroy', async_terminate)
win.show_all()
asyncio.run(async_gtk_main())


Amazing, I am new to concurrent programming stuffs like this - but I figured if I could GTK to run in in some kind of asynchronous way it would work, I just didn't know how to do it, and now you've perfectly done it!

Yes - this kind of snippet comes straightforward once some concepts had settled in ones mind - but really, there should be more snippets like this one around. If you do use any social networks where coding is on topic, I'd ask you to share this Q/A there.

Shouldn't intersection_update be difference_update instead? I'd expect you'd want to remove done tasks from event_tasks?

sure. sorry for that - I misplaced done for pending  - the other return value from .wait.
